# Embed list as part of string javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an html element inside javascript and for the onclick attribute i have to send a list as parameter.

```
var STOREID_LIST=["TEST","TEST"];

document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="<input type='checkbox' id='store_checkmain' onclick='check(["+STOREID_LIST+"],\"store_checkmain\");'/>";
```

In check function iam getting list of Html object element not the list as intended. Please

help me to solve this problem....

Comment: You're sure you are not just getting an array within an array, as that is what you are sending ?

Comment: No,Iam getting like this [object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not remove the `onClick` attribute and add a click listener on the checkbox instead?

```
var STOREID_LIST = ["TEST", "TEST"];
document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="<input type='checkbox' id='store_checkmain' />"

document.getElementById("store_checkmain").addEventListener("click", function() {
  check(STOREID_LIST, "store_checkmain");
});
```

Comment: I can do this but what is reason for getting that result.

Comment: @PRASANTH What do you mean?

Comment: Instead of getting a normal list why iam getting a list of html input element. Just want to clear my doubt!!!

Comment: Ah, you mean when you were doing this: `onclick='check(["+STOREID_LIST+"],\"store_checkmain\"`? It's because the `STOREID_LIST` is an `Object` (an `Array`), and when you try to put it in your HTML document, it is converted to a string (using a `toString` method, I think, which is built in in Object), and the `[object HTMLInputElement]` is what is returned by that method.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot more elegant using jQuery or something similar:

```
var myArray = ["test", "test"];

var input = $('<input></input>');
input.click(function() {
    check(myArray, "store_checkmain");
});

$('#check').append(input);
```

You can, however, also achieve the same by using "plain" dom manipulation.